# Switch component between tabs in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

Is there a way to switch components between tabs in `JTabbedPane` without creating new instances of these objects? Or any way to switch tabs?

When component is removed from `JTabbedPane` via `.remove(idx)` or `.removeTabAt(idx)` methods, the component is destroyed. Maybe there is a way to prevent destroying the object?

I am looking for a way to remove tab containing the component in order to add it back in nearest future but with some another index.

In other words, I just need to change the tab order. But it is important for me not to create new instances of components.

Comment: you can hide the component if you don't want to remove them.

Answer (score 3):

`JTabbedPane.removeTabAt` will only remove the tab, but not the component you've placed inside the tab. So to move the tab for a particular component you just insert a new tab for the component at the new position with `JTabbedPane.insertTab`, which will implicitly remove the old one. Or you can remove it yourself and add it again later on. Both methods work fine:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ReorderTabs {
    private static void addTab(final JTabbedPane tabbedPane, final String title) {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel content = new JLabel(title + " - content", JLabel.CENTER); 
        panel.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton toFrontButton = new JButton("|<");
        toFrontButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                // Re-insert the component in a new tab at the front. The tabbed pane will remove the old tab.
                tabbedPane.insertTab(title, null, panel, null, 0);
            }
        });
        panel.add(toFrontButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JButton toBackButton = new JButton(">|");
        toBackButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Remove the component from the tab. The component will not be destroyed ...
                int index = tabbedPane.indexOfComponent(panel);
                tabbedPane.removeTabAt(index);

                // ... and can be added again (or inserted at an arbitrary index with insertTab).
                tabbedPane.addTab(title, panel);
            }
        });
        panel.add(toBackButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        tabbedPane.addTab(title, panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
                addTab(tabbedPane, "Tab #1");
                addTab(tabbedPane, "Tab #2");
                addTab(tabbedPane, "Tab #3");
                addTab(tabbedPane, "Tab #4");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reorder Tabs Demo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(400, 200);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Added in getComponentAt (as the OP seems to have lost the original reference) and you have yourself an excellent answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the component if you don't want to remove them.

or you can switch the tabs using `jtpan.setEnabledAt(int tab_index, boolean enabled)`.

to set the index use `setSelectedIndex(int index)`

to hide the component use `componen.setVisible(false)`

Answer (score 0):

What about this dirty hack?

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
    final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane ();
    tabbedPane.addTab ("A", new JButton ("A"));
    tabbedPane.addTab ("B", new JButton ("B"));
    tabbedPane.addTab ("C", new JButton ("C"));
    tabbedPane.addTab ("D", new JButton ("D"));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane ().setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
    frame.getContentPane ().add (tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack ();
    frame.setVisible (true);

    Field pagesField = JTabbedPane.class.getDeclaredField ("pages");
    pagesField.setAccessible (true);
    final List <Object> pages = (List <Object>)pagesField.get (tabbedPane);

    while (true)
    {
        Thread.sleep (1000);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                Object o = pages.get (0);

                for (int i = 1; i < pages.size (); i++)
                    pages.set (i - 1, pages.get (i));

                pages.set (pages.size () - 1, o);

                tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex ((tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex () + pages.size () - 1) % pages.size ());

                tabbedPane.invalidate ();
                tabbedPane.repaint ();
            }
        });
    }
}
```